# Change text of drop down menu based on category id in rails 4, bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a job category drop-down menu, based on the selection from the menu the text has to change.Using Bootstrap 3 in this app, Have created a model of jobcategory and assigned its id to jobs.Is there a way to change the text of dropdown-menu when using`- Jobcategory.all.each do |jobcategory| %li= link_to jobcategory.name,`

```html
class Jobcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :jobs
end


class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :jobcategory
 validates :jobcategory,    presence: true
end

class JobsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index]


 def index
  if params[:jobcategory].blank?
   @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at DESC")
  else
   @jobcategory_id = Jobcategory.find_by(name: params[:jobcategory]).id
   @jobs =Job.where(jobcategory_id: @jobcategory_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end
 end


ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150512104628) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "jobcategories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "jobcategory_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "active"
  end


index.html.haml

%hearder
 %nav.navbar.navbar-job
  .container{class: "text-center"}
   %div{class: "btn-group"}
    %ul.dropdown
     %a.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-job{"data-toggle" => "dropdown","role" => "button"}
      %span{class: "caret"}
     %ul.dropdown-menu
      %li= link_to "All Jobs", jobs_path
      - Jobcategory.all.each do |jobcategory|
       %li= link_to jobcategory.name, jobs_path(jobcategory: jobcategory.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can.

You already have job category name in your parameters:

```
%ul.dropdown
  %a.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-job{ data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, role: 'button' }
    = params[:jobcategory] || 'Choose category' # in case it is `nil`
    %span.caret
```